# Google Calendar Events after 7pm are not retrieved until the Next Day using Google Events API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I've updated this because this question makes more sense than the original.  I'm still including the test code that I used to show what's happening.

Please see the comments for more up to date information on what I've found.

Executed API to grab events for today (there should be 1):

```
/calendar/v3/calendars/{calid}/events?calendarId={calid}&singleEvents=true&timeMin=2013-04-24T00:00:00.000Z&timeMax=2013-04-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

It retrieves nothing.   No events are returned.

If I execute the following (ie, the next day):

```
/calendar/v3/calendars/{calid}/events?calendarId={calid}&singleEvents=true&timeMin=2013-04-25T00:00:00.000Z&timeMax=2013-04-26T00:00:00.000Z
```

It retrieves the following which is set for the 24th (yet after 7pm), not the 25th:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"GZxpEFttRDAOmLHnWRxLHHWPGwk/01XVNYQjwJ5jTmd05uIgK9e6Uhw\"",
 "summary": "test calendar",
 "description": "test calendar",
 "updated": "2013-04-24T13:09:12.000Z",
 "timeZone": "America/Chicago",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"GZxpEFttRDAOmLHnWRxLHHWPGwk/Z2NhbDAwMDAxMzY2MTQ4ODczODI3MDAw\"",
   "id": "d1mdj3dasor22f0nm0lbohru7s",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=ZDFtZGozZGFzb3IyMmYwbm0wbGJvaHJ1N3MgYnZzdG9vbHMuY29tX2xidWt1ZmlnczJjMmFycjViODgycDVhYWhvQGc",
   "created": "2013-04-16T21:47:53.000Z",
   "updated": "2013-04-16T21:47:53.827Z",
   "summary": "this should happen 4/24/2013",
   "description": "testing event",
   "creator": {
    "email": "{my email address}",
    "displayName": "my name"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "{calid}",
    "displayName": "test calendar",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2013-04-24T21:21:19-05:00"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2013-04-24T21:21:19-05:00"
   },
   "iCalUID": "d1mdj3dasor22f0nm0lbohru7s@google.com",
   "sequence": 0,
   "extendedProperties": {
    "private": {
     "evtKey": "key"
    }
   },
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

It should be retrieving it for the first api call on the 24th, not the 2nd api call on the 25th unless I'm missing something.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've been playing around with this and I think it has something to do with the time on the calendar event.  

I found that if I updated the time of the event to any time before 7:00pm it would grab it.  7:00pm and after it wouldn't and you'd need to specify the next day if you wanted to grab it.

Is there a setting somewhere that says "dont grab things after a certain time?"  I'll go look as well in the settings but that seems quite odd.

Comment: Nope, I didn't find anything.  Some reason it's treating anything after 7pm as the next day when it tries to retrieve events by date.

Comment: I did some more digging and find that others are having related issues.  Back since 2008.  Is there anyone on the Google Team that can look into this?  It should be very easy to recreate.

Answer (score 1):

a bit late but if you still needs it. I think the event you retrieved `d1mdj3dasor22f0nm0lbohru7` seems to be in default timezone of the calendar, which is America/Chicago. That explains why it only showed when you set your query to 25th UTC time

Comment: I believe you are correct.  Interesting.  Now I need to look into how you query time using a time zone instead of UTC, or retrieve via UTC.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't use get request which has the param directly inserted in the link, but I guess it should be `timeMin=2013-04-24T00:00:00.000TAmercia/Chicago`. If it fails, don't blame me, cheers :). If you do use java, they have a google client library where you can set the timezone to the query object.

Comment: Actually what I need to do is convert the time entered on the input to UTC and send it that way instead of sending it as it's entered.  :)

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what the solution is here?  I have the same issue but I am not so sure how you solved it.